# Proble with Heroku JDK version

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a springboot application on Heroku via CLI. My problem is that Heroku defaults to JDK 1.8 and I would need JDK 17. I have in system.properties -     `java.runtime.version=17` and in pom.xml -         `<java.version>17</java.version>`     , but Heroku always installs JDK 1.8 when deploying the jar file. Any advice please?

I didn't find an answer here that would help me

`cerma@cerma-GL503VD:~/git/vendaSkola/target$ heroku deploy:jar VendaSchool3.jar -a vendaskola1  ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.60.1 to 8.7.1. Uploading VendaSchool3.jar -----> Packaging application...        - app: vendaskola1        - including: VendaSchool3.jar -----> Creating build...        - file: slug.tgz        - size: 17MB -----> Uploading build...        - success -----> Deploying... remote:  remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/jvm remote: -----> heroku-deploy app detected remote: -----> Installing OpenJDK 1.8... done remote: -----> Discovering process types remote:        Procfile declares types -> web remote:  remote: -----> Compressing... remote:        Done: 69.3M remote: -----> Launching... remote:        Released v3`

I try write to system.properties      `java.runtime.version=17, pom.xml - <java.version>17</java.version>,<java.runtime.version>17</java.runtime.version>`

Comment: deploying this way, heroku probably doesn't see the `system.properties` file. try to include it with the command option `-i, --includes FILES   # list of files to include in the slug`: https://github.com/heroku/plugin-java

Answer (score 0):

When you run the application in heroku it is actually taking it from the Heroku instance but not from the setting specified with in the application .

Try to run the application using the following command

> heroku run java -version -a yourapplicationName